# Clear input values upon different dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this dropdown list which upon selection of a value called 'Callback' two input boxes appear where I can input a date and time. If I again select a different value from the dropdown list then the two input boxes are hidden.

My issue is when the two input boxes disappear upon selection of a different value then I wish for it to clear the date and time that was entered. Could someone show how that can be done?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Callback').hide();
  $("#lead_status").change(function() {
    $('#Callback').hide('slow');
    $("#" + this.value).show('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Lead Status</label>
  <select name="lead_status" id="lead_status" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="Interested">Interested</option>
    <option value="Not Interested">Not Interested</option>
    <option value="Hung Up">Hung Up</option>
    <option value="Call Got Disconnected">Call Got Disconnected</option>
    <option value="Callback">Callback</option>
  </select>
  <div id="Callback">
    <br/>
    <label for="callback_date">Callback Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="callback_time" class="form-control" />
    <br />
    <label for="callback_time">Callback Time:</label>
    <input type="time" name="callback_time" class="form-control" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you require set `val('')` on the hidden inputs within the content you toggle.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $callback = $('#Callback');

  $("#lead_status").change(function() {
    $callback.hide('slow', function() {
      $(this).find('input').val('')
    });
    $("#" + this.value).show('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#Callback {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Lead Status</label>
  <select name="lead_status" id="lead_status" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="Interested">Interested</option>
    <option value="Not Interested">Not Interested</option>
    <option value="Hung Up">Hung Up</option>
    <option value="Call Got Disconnected">Call Got Disconnected</option>
    <option value="Callback">Callback</option>
  </select>
  <div id="Callback">
    <br />
    <label for="callback_date">Callback Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="callback_time" class="form-control" />
    <br />
    <label for="callback_time">Callback Time:</label>
    <input type="time" name="callback_time" class="form-control" />
  </div>
```

Also note in the above example that the `#Callback` element is hidden by default using CSS, not JS, so that you avoid a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Comment: Thanks but in my system having an issue. by default the callback time and date fields are showing when page loads

Comment: Did you add the line of CSS I showed in the example?

Comment: Yes i did use the css but on page load its not hiding

Comment: Use the DOM inspector to check the CSS on the element and ensure the rule is specific enough to override any other styles on the element.

Comment: You're right it was overriding , thanks alot @Rory for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help